# Receive Data from UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, custom-cell

I have the following code set:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nibObjs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellView" owner:nil options:nil];
        //cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        for(id currentObj in nibObjs)
        {
            if([currentObj isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
            {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObj;
            }

        }
    }

    AssessmentDetail * anAssess = [module.assessmentDetails4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[cell labelAssessment] setText:anAssess.assessmentName4];
    return cell;
}
```

In my custom cell there is a `UISlider`. What I would like to do is use a button to retrieve the value of each UISlider from each row so I can get a total value.

I thought about doing this but I'm not certain on where to go from there:

```
- (IBAction) calculateTotal:(id)sender {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycle through the subviews of the UITableView:

```
- (IBAction) calculateTotal:(id)sender {
    NSArray *subViews = [myTableView subviews];
    float total;

    for (int i = 0; i < subViews.count; i++)
    {
         id obj = [subViews objectAtIndex:i];
         if ([obj isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]])
         {
              total += [[obj getMySlider] getValue];
         }
    }

    // do something with total
}
```

Comment: One thing to note: if you have the cells truly dequeuable, then if you have more than a full page of cells, this will only return the values of the cells on the screen.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I kind of gathered that when I was trying the code out. Thanks again